# My req.on('end') does not fire. How can fix this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request

I just started learning Node.js and I'm trying to print the value of an input that is submitted through a form. The `req.on('data')` always fires but the `req.on('end')` never does.
Please can someone tell me what's wrong?

My entire code can be found bellow

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    const url = req.url;
    const method = req.method;

    if (url === '/') {
        res.write('<html>');
        res.write('<head><title>Enter Message</title></head>');
        res.write(
            '<body><form action="/message" method="POST"><input type="text" name="message"><button type="submit">Send</button></form></body>'
        );
        res.write('</html>');
        return res.end();
    }

    if (url === '/message' && method === 'POST') {
        const body = [];
        req.on('data', (chunk) => {
            console.log(chunk);
            body.push(chunk);
        });
        req.on('end', () => {
            const parsedBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
            console.log(parsedBody);
        });

        res.statusCode = 302;
        res.setHeader('Location', '/');
        return res.end();
    }
    // process.exit();
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.write('<html>');
    res.write('<head><title>My First Page</title></head>');
    res.write('<body><h1>Hello from my Node.js Sever!</h1></body>');
    res.write('</html>');
    res.end();
});
server.listen(4000);
```

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Ok so I fixed it but the fix doesn't make sense

I had to move the `res.*` calls at the end of the `if (url === '/message' && method === 'POST')` statement and put them in the `res.on('end')` event handler:

```
 req.on('end', () => {
        const parsedBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
        console.log(parsedBody);

        res.statusCode = 302;
        res.setHeader('Location', '/');
        res.end();
    });
```

Then I had to remove the `res.*` calls after the if statement:

```
//res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
//res.write('<html>');
//res.write('<head><title>My First Page</title></head>');
//res.write('<body><h1>Hello from my Node.js Sever!</h1></body>');
//res.write('</html>');
//res.end();
```

So now the whole code looks like this:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    const url = req.url;
    const method = req.method;

    if (url === '/') {
        res.write('<html>');
        res.write('<head><title>Enter Message</title></head>');
        res.write(
            '<body><form action="/message" method="POST"><input type="text" name="message"><button type="submit">Send</button></form></body>'
        );
        res.write('</html>');
        return res.end();
    }

    if (url === '/message' && method === 'POST') {
        const body = [];
        req.on('data', (chunk) => {
            console.log(chunk);
            body.push(chunk);
        });
        req.on('end', () => {
            const parsedBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
            console.log(parsedBody);

            res.statusCode = 302;
            res.setHeader('Location', '/');
            return res.end();
        });

    }
    // process.exit();
    //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    //res.write('<html>');
    //res.write('<head><title>My First Page</title></head>');
    //res.write('<body><h1>Hello from my Node.js Sever!</h1></body>');
    //res.write('</html>');
    //res.end();
});
server.listen(4000);
```

Any insight to why this fixed the problem would be most appreciated.

Comment: can you check if `            const parsedBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
` line is not throwing any error? basically add console statement first

Comment: @AshishModi I tried that, the console statement didn't run

Comment: Is there a possibility that the client will terminate the connection? You are responding to the request immediately. Try listening to the `'aborted'` and `'close'` events.

Comment: @SamiHult I did `req.on('close', (err) => {
   console.log(err);
  });`  It printed undefined

Comment: @SamiHult Then I tried `req.connection.on('close', (err) => {
   console.log(err);
  });` and it waits for about 2 seconds and returns false. What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little research I found what was wrong. The `req.on('end')` event handlers were just registered but not fired since it's asynchronous. So it moves on to the next block of code which is:

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
res.write('<html>');
res.write('<head><title>My First Page</title></head>');
res.write('<body><h1>Hello from my Node.js Sever!</h1></body>');
res.write('</html>');
res.end();
```

And this blocks the `req.on('end')` from executing as the request stream had been closed.

What I should have done was to return on the `req.on('end')` event handler:

```
return req.on('end', () => {
    const parsedBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
    console.log(parsedBody);

    res.statusCode = 302;
    res.setHeader('Location', '/');
    return res.end();
});
```

This would prevent the block of `req.*` statements at after the `if (url === '/message' && method === 'POST')` statement from executing.

Comment: I revised my answer - I had missed that with my fix, the execution would continue to that "My First Page" block, which it shouldn't. Why your code works is that you removed `res.end()` from the end. I think you should return in the `if` instead; you probably want default handling there anyways.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

The original answer still applies, but I missed one thing: The `if` block must return as in the original post - otherwise the response manipulation after it will be run, which again closes the req/res streams.

Returning or not returning on the event handlers makes no difference. It will not affect the execution and the returned value is not used anywhere.

So for the revised fix:

```
    if (url === '/message' && method === 'POST') {
        // ...
        req.on('end', () => {
            const parsedBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
            console.log(parsedBody);

            res.statusCode = 302;
            res.setHeader('Location', '/');
            res.end();
        });
        return;
```

**Original answer**

I'm not an expert on node http module, so if anyone is willing to fill in, please do so. That said:

Two seconds implies a timeout on the underlying connection (the actual socket, which is probably kept alive for additional requests). This is normal.

I suppose what happens here is that since you essentially ask to close the response stream before you have depleted the request stream, the request stream will be closed as well even though there would be more data available. Mind you, the actual underlying connection is two-way and ending the response transmit implies that you have no further interest in the incoming message.

To fix this, move your `res.*` calls to the `'end'` event handler:

```
        req.on('end', () => {
            const parsedBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
            console.log(parsedBody);

            res.statusCode = 302;
            res.setHeader('Location', '/');
            res.end();
        });
```

Comment: I just tried this and now the streams don't close and the page is never redirected back to `/` because `res.on('end')` is still never fired. I feel there maybe be a problem with my node or something

Comment: That is unexpected and should indicate that not all data was consumed. Which node version? Does the stream emit `error` events?

Comment: Also, is the received request valid? How is it generated and can you share the whole HTTP message?

Comment: Ok so I just started node so I have no idea what you're talking about but no i don't think the stream emits `error` event. My node version is v12.8.1

Comment: I just revised the question. I was able to get the `req.on('end')` to fire but I kind off need an explanation to why it worked